# drupal 6 view: 'sibling' node reference

Tags: drupal-6, reference, drupal-views

*apologies if this has been answered--this seems like a common enough problem, but i didn't find anything.*

in a drupal 6 view, i need to find other nodes that reference same node as current node, sort of like sibling references. this is for a student/parent directory.

the view is a list of students (one content type), the parents per student ('parent' being another content type, node referenced from the 'student' type) and the siblings of students (the stickler)--these are 'student' nodes that share the same 'parent' node references.

something like:

```
student  |   parents     |  siblings
--------------------------------------
jane d. | mom. d, dad d. | jeff d.

jeff d. | mom. d, dad d. | jane d.
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in views you should use Relationships and View arguments (if required).
via relationships, you can set your rules (parent > student). Also, please bear in mind that if you're using relationship and want to access related nodes' fields, in display fields, you should choose use relationship, so it will print fields of related nodes, not the parent one.

Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask more, I will be glad to help.